# How to use legend only once in a subplot for a for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

[image: How to use legend only once?]

I am using a for loop and trying to figure out how to use legend only once, either on top or below the subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plot_loc = 1
total_t = 0.1
dt = [1e-4, 1e-3, 1.5e-3] 
for n in dt:
#
#
#
    t, y_explicit = explicit_euler(total_t, n)
    t, y_implicit = implicit_euler(total_t, n)
    y_analytical = analytical(total_t,n)

    plt.subplot(3,1,plot_loc)
    plt.plot(t, y_explicit, color = 'blue')
    plt.plot(t, y_implicit, color = 'black')
    plt.plot(t,y_analytical,linestyle='dashed',color = 'orange')    
    plt.legend(['Explicit','Implicit','Analytical'])
    plot_loc+=1

plt.tight_layout(pad=1.0)
plt.show()
```

---

> If you only want the legend on the last subplot, then just move `plt.legend` outside the loop.

In that case it plots it in the third subplot (please see the result below), which I don't want. I want it either in the first subplot, below the plots or in the title.

[image: legend outside for loop]

Comment: If you only want the legend on the last subplot, then just move plt.legend outside the loop

Comment: In that case it plots it in the third subplot (please see the edited post), which I don't want. I want it either in the first subplot, below the plots or in the title.

Answer (score 0):

As Mikael suggested, you should first move the legend code line outside the for loop. Then, use `bbox_to_anchor()` to set the position of the legend.

As you are using `plt.plot()` to plot each subplot, once you have completed the loop, the plot referred to will be the last one. So, the coordinates will be with respect to the last subplot. I have used -0.25 to set the height so that the plot is below the last subplot. Do adjust this to make sure the legend comes you exactly where you want it.

Also, notice that you can use `ncols=3` to show the legend in 3 columns so that the plot looks better. You can remove it if it doesnt suit your requirement. The updated code (with random data) and legend line is given below. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plot_loc = 1
total_t = 0.1
dt = [1e-4, 1e-3, 1.5e-3] 

t=np.linspace(0,0.1,101)

for n in dt:
#    t, y_explicit = explicit_euler(total_t, n)
#    t, y_implicit = implicit_euler(total_t, n)
#    y_analytical = analytical(total_t,n)
    y_explicit = np.random.uniform(low=-0.001, high=0, size=(101,))
    y_implicit = np.random.uniform(low=-0.001, high=0, size=(101,))
    y_analytical = np.random.uniform(low=-0.001, high=0, size=(101,))
    
    plt.subplot(3,1,plot_loc)
    plt.plot(t, y_explicit, color = 'blue')
    plt.plot(t, y_implicit, color = 'black')
    plt.plot(t,y_analytical,linestyle='dashed',color = 'orange')    
    plot_loc+=1

plt.legend(['Explicit','Implicit','Analytical'], bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, -0.25), ncol=3)

plt.tight_layout(pad=1.0)
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]